# Check for Ruby env variable

Tags: ruby

I tried to check for env variable in jenkins build using this code:

```
if ENV['test_environment'].is_set?
 env = ENV['test_environment']
else
.....
end
```

But I get error: `send_req.rb:8:in`': undefined method `is_set?' for "staging_psp":String (NoMethodError)`

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: It tells you right there that the method `is_set?` does not exist. Easiest fix would be `if !ENV['test_environment'].nil?`

Comment: Can you recommend better solution?

Comment: The most idiomatic way is in the linked question: `env = ENV['test_environment'] || "your default value"`